# I installed all screensavers I could find, but none are listed in settings, in Fedora 21 Beta

Tags: fedora, settings, testing, screensaver, xscreensaver

I installed these:

```
yum install xscreensaver-base xscreensaver-extras xscreensaver-extras-base xscreensaver-gl-base xscreensaver-gl-extras
```

**But there are no screensavers listed in settings:**
[image]
Anyone got any idea's or I just file a bug?

EDIT #1

I've tried to restart the system after installing the screensavers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I installed some packages which I found after reading [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=196232), these are the packages I installed:

```
kdeartwork                 x86_64    4.14.3-1.fc21     fedora    2.2 M 
 kdeartwork-common          noarch    4.14.3-1.fc21     fedora     32 k 
 kdeartwork-kxs             x86_64    4.14.3-1.fc21     fedora     75 k 
 kdeartwork-screensavers    x86_64    4.14.3-1.fc21     fedora    652 k 
 kdeartwork-wallpapers      noarch    4.14.3-1.fc21     fedora    113 M
```

with this command:

```
yum --enablerepo=updates-testing install kdeartwork*
```

Now I have some screen-savers to choose from in settings, but I don't think the other screen-savers I installed previously show up, so I'll have to investigate when I have the time and post back if no one with more knowledge answers.